# apache error 403 forbidden - qgis

Tags: apache, qgis

I just Install Apache 2.2.14(win32)  mod_fcgid/2.3.6 on Windows 10 x64

this is part of my httpd.conf

```html
#the path below is correct!
include "C:\OSGeo4W/httpd.d/httpd_qgis.conf"
```

and this is https_qgis.conf

```html
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .exe

LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so

DefaultInitEnv PATH "C:\OSGeo4W\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-@grassversion@\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-@grassversion@\lib;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem"
DefaultInitEnv QGIS_PREFIX_PATH "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis"
DefaultInitEnv QT_PLUGIN_PATH "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\qtplugins;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qt4\plugins"
DefaultInitEnv TEMP "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp"
DefaultInitEnv PYTHONHOME "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27"

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:\OSGeo4W/bin/"
ScriptAlias /qgis/ C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/bin/
#ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/bin/


<Directory "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/bin/">
    SetHandler fcgid-script
    Options ExecCGI
    #Order allow,deny
    #Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Apache start correctly, without errors, but if I try to browse this address(for test):

http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

I have this error 403:

**You don't have permission to access /qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe on this server.**

How can I resolve ?!

The path I write above, are correct !

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can't write files on at the address. Are you running your computer as an administrator? You can check if you go to the address and right-click on the folder, go to properties and see if the box "read-only" is checked. In the security tab you can change this if you have the permissions. Hope this helps